# How to ingest a new js file using Chrome local overrides

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use Chromes local override feature to ingest my own JS file.
Basically, I override the index.html and add my script source to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://realwebsite.com/own.js"></script>
```

I then created a new file named own.js into

```
<local overrides folder>/realwebsite.com/own.js
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://realwebsite.com/own.js'
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I could instead use the local file path in the src attribute. However, if specified explicitly as a local resource, this is not allowed in Chrome. I can use the Chrome flag --allow-file-access-from-files, however, this is certainly not the best idea.

Any better idea? Thanks!